# Twisted Python, using ssl.CertificateOptions when switching from plain text to secure connection

Tags: python, authentication, ssl, twisted, starttls

Following advice from Jean-Paul Calderone here on SO, I'm trying to modify the twisted "starttls_server" sample below to support  the use of ssl.ClientCertificateOptions, to allow me to specify my private key, certificate, and trusted roots, as per http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/14.0.0/api/twisted.internet.ssl.CertificateOptions.html

```
from twisted.internet import ssl, protocol, defer, task, endpoints
from twisted.protocols.basic import LineReceiver
from twisted.python.modules import getModule

class TLSServer(LineReceiver):
    def lineReceived(self, line):
        print("received: " + line)
        if line == "STARTTLS":
            print("-- Switching to TLS")
            self.sendLine('READY')
            self.transport.startTLS(self.factory.options)

def main(reactor):
    certData = getModule(__name__).filePath.sibling('server.pem').getContent()
    cert = ssl.PrivateCertificate.loadPEM(certData)
    factory = protocol.Factory.forProtocol(TLSServer)
    factory.options = cert.options()
    endpoint = endpoints.TCP4ServerEndpoint(reactor, 8000)
    endpoint.listen(factory)
    return defer.Deferred()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import starttls_server
    task.react(starttls_server.main)
```

My understanding is that I effectively need to replace the `cert = ssl.PrivateCertificate...` and `cert.options = ssl.PrivateCertificate....` lines with something like `certopts = ssl.CertificateOptions(privateKey=pKeyData, certificate=certData, trustRoot=caCertsData)` (having read the appropriate files in to certData, caCertsData, and pKeyData) and then pass this in to `factory.options` - but without pasting every variant of code I've tried, I've yet to work this out correctly - my efforts have produced varying results from the classic "OpenSSL.crypto.Error: []" - through to seemingly just dumping the contents of my 3 PEM files to screen and exiting!

Can anyone enlighten me? Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cert.options()` is already returning a `CertificateOptions`.  The problem is that `options` takes authorities (as `Certificate` objects) as positional args, and doesn't let you pass through all the other configuration values through, so you probably want to construct a `CertificateOptions` directly.

Just change the `factory.options = cert.options()` line to `factory.options = ssl.CertificateOptions(...)`.

However, `CertificateOptions` takes a pyOpenSSL `PKey` object as its `privateKey`, not the key data.  So you'll need to use OpenSSL APIs to load that key, or you can extract it from a `PrivateCertificate`.

[If you read the signature of `CertificateOptions` very carefully](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/14.0.2/api/twisted.internet.ssl.CertificateOptions.html), the required types should be fairly clear.  You may also need to consult the [pyOpenSSL](http://pyopenssl.readthedocs.org/) documentation as well.

Comment: Hi @Glyph, many thanks again. So I have my server running, with `factory.options = ssl.CertificateOptions(privateKey=pKeyData, certificate=certData, trustRoot=caCert)` (with those three values loaded in from file as (I believe) appropriate. When my client connects however, the server errors with `exceptions.TypeError: cert must be an X509 instance` - client supplies a pem copy of the cert. Can you enlighten me here? Or would it make more sense to raise this as a new question? Thank you!

Comment: Make sure you're passing certificates to `CertificateOptions` as pyOpenSSL X509 instances - not as Twisted's `PrivateCertificate` type.

Comment: Hi @Jean-PaulCalderone... I'm reading my 3 params in from file using filePath.sibling.('xxxxx').getContent(). caCert is a PEM with just `BEGIN CERTIFICATE[data]END CERTIFICATE`. certData is the same, but also with a `BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY[data]END RSA PRIVATE KEY`. pKeyData is different (as I believe expected) - containing `Private-Key (1024 bit)/modulus/[hex stuff]/publicExponent: 65537 (.... etc)`. Is this not correct? I do not use an ssl.[Private]Certificate in there at all for these 3 parameters?

Comment: If you have the data as strings, you need to load it into pyOpenSSL objects.  See `OpenSSL.crypto.load_{certificate,privatekey}`.

Comment: (That's how you get the `PKey` object Glyph mentioned)